# how to ignore span with List<WebElement>

Tags: selenium

I am trying to extract `Main Text1` and `Main Text2` from below DOM structure.

```
<div class="origination">
<div class="origin">
<h3>
Main Text1
<span class="info">Test1</span>
</h3>
<div class="test">
</div>
</div>
<div class="origin">
<h3>
Main Text2
<span class="info">Test2</span>
</h3>
<div class="test">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have used below xpath with text() to identify header without span

```
  @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='origination']/div[*]/h3/text()")
    List<WebElement> content;
```

I am trying to print header element without span using below code

```
for (WebElement element: content){
 System.out.println("Header" + element.getText());
    }
```

But I am getting error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Timed out after 15 seconds. List elements not found

However, when I used the same XPath on the firepath elements get highlighted in the DOM structure but not on to the page.

Comment: The xpath in your findBy does not return webElements, it returns a text array.  Leave off the "/text()" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
spanText = element.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='info']")).getText()
element.getText().Replace(spanText, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I have already tried this but I am getting Main Text1
Test1 in this case. I want only Main Text1.

Comment: Do you understand my question?  I want to ignore span element which is present under h3

Comment: you have to use `.getAttribute("innerText")` rather `.gettext()`.